# this get method seems to be working but there are errors in the console

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I have the script below:

```
disallow_part = {
  disallow_part: '#disallow-part'

  init: ->
    @setListeners()

  setListeners: ->
    $(@disallow_part).live 'click', ->
      partId = $(this).data("part-id")
      augmentId = $(this).data("augment-id")
      $.get("/parts/#{partId}/disallow_part_for_augment/#{augmentId}", null, 'script')
}
```

It seems to be hitting that route because records are being added to the db but in the console I get this error.

> GET http:***/parts 404 (Not Found)

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Does "/parts/#{partId}/disallow_part_for_augment/#{augmentId}" correctly render? Can you check the url that being send

Comment: yes, that path resolves the way it should without an error. Whether, I hit via the browser or get method it still adds a record.

Answer (score 0):

That's a 404 error being returned from your server: you sent the request to the wrong URL.

Examine the request you've sent on your browser's deverloper console's network tab (it'll probably show up in red, because it was unsuccessful)

Comment: Why did he send the wrong URL? He said that it works.

Comment: Well there has to be some reason why a server would respond with 404. He said a record is successfully added - I presumed that's not the effect of this GET request. Hard to tell without the rest of the code... maybe several  requests are sent?

Comment: I don't see why a GET request should not be able to manipulate DB records. Maybe a counter is incremented to register views? Of course, he provides very little info, but the backend code doesnt seem relevant at this point, since the ajax call seems successful and @isea does not seem to be willfully returning a 404. You might be right, maybe several calls are made, but judging from the code, that's a stretch.

Comment: Because a GET request *should* be idempotent, and this top level semantic of the request should not be broken. It can be, of course.

Comment: Of course, you are right. I didn't comment on isea using a GET request where he instead should probably use a POST/PUT, because a correctly configured GET request would not return a 404, even if it's not idempotent. It's not safe, but it should be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Since the request seems to be understood correctly by your backend, the one plausible cause is a discrepancy in **[content-type headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)**.

1. Check your browser console's network section.
2. What does the http header look like in the **request**?
3. What does the http header look like in the **response**?

Have your eyes on the content-type fields. Maybe your ajax request expects **json**, but the server returns **text/html**?

Try playing with the headers of your ajax to send and expect the right data types, and I'm sure you'll fix it in no time.